# What musical instrument is "batería"?

Tags: traducción, música

The direct translation I found for "batería" is "battery" (makes sense), but in a list of musical instruments, what does it signify? Is it drums? Percussion?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1536&bih=784&q=bateria&oq=bateria&gs_l=img.3..0l10.797.3748.0.5108.9.8.1.0.0.0.104.449.7j1.8.0....0...1ac.1.37.img..0.9.452.I4j7N6XaP1o , in spanish like english exist words that are homonymous, you can get they meaning by the context

Comment: You're right - that works right off the bat (as does bing), whereas translate.com, also powered by google, failed ignominiously.

Comment: Why to use translators if you can acess a wikipedia article, whose title would lead you to the Spanish word you´re looking for?

Comment: In English, a set of cannons is called a *battery*.  This is the origin of Battery Park in southern Manhattan.  Likewise, in Spanish *batería*  was short for a kit of drums.  Maybe *batería de tambores*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it is "**(the) drums**", "**set of drums**" or "**a drum kit**"

See examples at http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drums#examples_box

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia [bateria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateria) means “drum kit” in Portuguese and Spanish.  The term is also used to refer to a group of people (drummers, for the most part) who play [batucada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batucada).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, "batería" refers to the drums, but it is also used to talk about "the drummer", that is, the person playing the drums

Answer (score 0):

> The direct translation I found for "batería" is "battery" (makes
>   sense)

Why does it make sense?  Is it because batería sounds like `battery`?  That wouldn't merit any sense; comparing it to the English sound.

It makes sense that `batería` would mean drums because the verb `batir` means... `to beat`, which can also mean to `strike`... as in to strike a match.    Batería literally would mean a striker (to an engine, to the drums, to a person, etc...)

According to RAE

batería : http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=OFRgrNsMWDXX2ykpUc7x

batir : http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=94EX430WrDXX2NTXeynu

So, ... now it makes sense that batería would mean battery, not because they sound similar but because they both stem from the same root latin word.

You can also have a baseball bat, but it is not the same as a vampire bat; a creature that doesn't beat anything... other than its wings maybe.

Comment: I don't think that "batería" comes from "batir", but from it's definition as "set of things", like "battery" for "set of guns", or "batería de cocina" for "cookware set".

Comment: A set of things would be called an `equipo`.  Un equipo de baterías de cocina would be `a set of kitchen cookware`, meaning they are all the same brand and complement each other, otherwise, baterías de cocina refers only to a collection of pots and pans, both of which could be used as drums, :D